# Metronome count problem left foot

Tags: metronomes, bass-drum

I am a new drummer and i start drumming without counting from left foot, at that time i feld i always had tempo problem. it was really diffcult for me. How hard i could pratice on practising pad but finally i realized that i had to count by left foot. i start practising but it's really diffcult for me to make stable balance between two foot left as well as right. So suggest me techniques as well as tips ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying balanced while moving both feet essentially comes down to proper setup and practice. If your drum seat is set too low or too high that could cause balance problems. Experiment with your seat hight to find the position that gives you the best balance. Next, make sure your pedals are in a comfortable position and aren't putting you off balance. A great method to setup your drumkit is to start with just the drum seat and then do a little "air drumming" while hitting your feet on the floor to see where your feet naturally want to land while you play. The positions of your feet are where you want to place your kick and hihat pedals and then set up the rest of the kit around your bass drum and hihat. You might need to shift things around to make it all fit but this gives you a good starting point.

Once your kit is setup correctly and you feel comfortable and balance, then try working on bass drum and hihat coordination and independence exercises. Searching on Youtube will give you lots of great exercises and things to practice to build your foot coordination and balance. Start with just keeping basic time with your left foot (as you are already doing) while playing the rest of the kit and then move on to more complicated exercises with your feet.

Finally, time keeping and keeping good tempo is something that most, if not all new musicians struggle with in general. Benny Greb did an amazing lesson with Drumeo about time keeping and groove that provides very practical exercises to work on that will help you get better at this. You can watch the lesson here:

That lesson breifly touches on some of the topics from Benny Greb's DVD "The Art and Science of Groove". I have his DVD and it goes even more indepth than the Drumeo lesson and I can't recommend his DVD enough! IMO it's an essential DVD for all musicians, not just drummers, because the concepts he teaches can easily be applied to any instrument.

Answer (score 2):

Practice slowly and accurately to a metronome click.   Check with your teacher that you aren't doing anything silly.   If you haven't got a teacher, get one, if only for a few consultation lessons.